# Cut infinity float

Tags: java, android

I've got float in my app, which generates infinity:

```
float fx = eddystoneAdvEvtCurr_mA * txTime_ms / (eddystoneFrame.interval / 1000);
```

It returns `61,333333(3)`. I tried to convert it to `String` and split, convert to `int`, but nothing works. Can I just make `61,33` or `61,3` from it? When I cast it to `int` it returns strange value: `2147483647`. It looks like a simple thing but I've spent lot of time to figure it out.

Comment: The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647

Comment: `61,333333(3)` what notation is this?

Comment: What are the values of `eddystoneAdvEvtCurr_mA`, `txTime_ms` and `eddystoneFrame.interval`?

Comment: Ok, I understand but this doesn't solve my problem ;)

Comment: Is your float 61,3333 or infinity? You state both in your question.

Comment: Curr 4,6 : tx  4 :  Interval 300

Comment: @marstran it's infinity

Comment: What's the thing with 61.3333 then...?

Answer (score 0):

You can cut of the digits like this:

```
float fx = eddystoneAdvEvtCurr_mA * txTime_ms / (eddystoneFrame.interval / 1000);

float fxRounded= ((int)(100*fx))/100.f
```

fxRounded should be `61,33`

Here the idea:

1. multiply the float by a power of 10 accordingly to the number of decimal places you want.
2. cast the result to an `int` (this cuts of all digits behind the comma)
3. divide by the the same power of 10 (as in 1.) but make it a float or double division (therefore use `/100.` and not `/100`) to keep the resulting digits right of the comma.

Here is my tested code: it prints: 61.33

```
public class T{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    float fx = 61.3333333333f;
    float fxRounded=((int)(100*fx))/100.f;
    System.err.println(""+fxRounded);
  }
}
```

Comment: It returns 2.1474836E7

Comment: fixed the error. Closing bracket was at the wrong place.

Comment: still  2.147483647E7 :/

Comment: I wrote a mini program and tested it (worked) see the class I added and run it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how the floats are stored in the JVM, you can take a look at this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). (you can also take a look at the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3))

If you want to have a fix precision, you shall use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). example :

```
BigDecimal ten = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);
BigDecimal three = BigDecimal.valueOf(3);
int precision = 2;
System.out.println(ten.divide(three, precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING));
```

Output :

> 3.34

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Math.round();
```

to round of a double or a float value

Comment: I know, but it returns 2.1474836E7